# Where do I have to put JQuery in Ruby On Rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am implementing in Ruby on Rails.What I want to do works with Jquery. What i want to do is just: I have a file_field_tag, to let the user upload a file, when the user selects a file, the submit button has been enabled. So the user can't click on the button as long as he didn't select a file.

This is the JQuery which I've written

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $('input:file').change(
            function(){
                if ($(this).val()) {
                    $('input:submit').attr('disabled',false);
                    // or, as has been pointed out elsewhere:
                    // $('input:submit').removeAttr('disabled'); 
                } 
            }
            );
    });
```

and my view looks like:

```
<h2>Import projects and users</h2>


<% form_tag({:action => 'match'}, {:multipart => true, :id => 'file_form_id'}) do %>
<fieldset title="File">
    <legend>File</legend>
<table>
   <tr>
     <td>
      <label for="dump_file">
        Select a CSV File :
      </label>

         </td>
         <td >
           <%= file_field_tag 'file', :size => 500 %></p>
         </td>
       </tr>   
     </table>

           <%= submit_tag 'Submit', :disabled => true -%>


    <% end -%>
```

I think that this is correct. But where do i have to put this javascript? I really don't know where to put it. I've read to put it in application.js, but when I do this, nothing happens. The button stays disabled. Somebody who knows what I am missing?

Comment: I think 2.3.11. Not Rails 3, but this has its reasons.

Comment: you THINK? run in console rails -v

Comment: Yes it is 2.3.11. Sorry, bad choice of words ;)

Answer (score 0):

looks like you removed those require lines:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into including all the files listed below.
// Add new JavaScript/Coffee code in separate files in this directory and they'll automatically
// be included in the compiled file accessible from http://example.com/assets/application.js
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: So above my application.js? But I think when it is in this file, it won't work, because how does application.js knows when it is this form? I never give a name of the form in the jquery?

Comment: in rails 3 you have gem 'jquery-rails' by default in gemfile

Comment: and application.js will run this code on each page. even if this form is not rendered. dont worry about this :)

Comment: If he's on 2.3.11, he's probably not using a Gemfile, sprockets, or any of this new-fangled fun stuff.

Comment: So how can i reach my goal ;)?

Answer (score 0):

The javascript you wrote goes in /public/javascripts/application.js. You also need a copy of jquery.js or jquery.min.js in /public/javascripts/ or you need to include one of the publicly available versions. Make sure jquery is loaded in your `<head>` before your application.js.

Example:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js', 'application' %>
```